# Observers added unexpectedly in LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, android-room, android-livedata

I am trying to implement Room and Livedata in my application.
I use LiveData to be updated on changes.

I have a ViewModel which returns a LiveData object (returned by Room via a Dao class) and I observe this LiveData in my Views.

I have made breakpoints in each place where I add an observer like that :

```
mSessionViewModel.sessionsList.observe(mActivity, Observer<List<Session>> { list ->
        setSessionList(list!!)
    })
```

However, when I am in debug and I check the mObservers variable of the LiveData object, I see that mIterators increase without the breakpoints where I have the creation of the observers reached (like above) :

[image: screenshot of the LiveData object in debug]

Can anyone explain me this behavior? It seems that observers are added even if I don't create new ones...
It could eventually be the number of times a change in the LiveData has been detected but I wouldn't expect the list of observers to increase.

Comment: AFAIK , they will keep on adding, but android will have the old observers deleted eventually after some time, and you dont have to worry about the number of observers increasing as they are managed

Comment: Depends on where you have this code: `mSessionViewModel.sessionsList.observe(`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced something similar causing multiple messages to pop up upon navigating back to the same fragment.  I fixed it by making sure the binding takes place in onCreate rather than onCreateView

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        initObservables()
    }
```